# Get seekbar progress from Dialog

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build a dialog that uses a custom layout, but i cant get the volume and gain values from the seekbar, it gives a nullpointer exception.
Here's the code:

```
        Dialog soundoptions= new Dialog(this);
    soundoptions.setContentView(R.layout.soundoptions);

    soundoptions.setTitle("Sound Options");
    soundoptions.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SeekBar vs=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.volume);
            SeekBar vg=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.gain);
            vg.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                        boolean fromUser) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    gain=progress;

                }
            });
           vs.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                volume=progress;

            }
        });
```

Comment: In which line exactly do you get the exception? It helps to find the answer sooner.

Comment: post the stacktrace please

Comment: its on the vg.setOnSeekBarChangeListener line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vs and vg are null.

Use ...

```
SeekBar vs=(SeekBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.volume);
SeekBar vg=(SeekBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.gain);
```

Note the "dialog" ...

Comment: just beated me to it! ahaha i will accept this as the right anwser!